# Filemaker Pro database query

Tags: filemaker

I was this was a complicated question....but unfortunately it seems to be very simple, just with the nuance of a FileMaker Pro (v12) database. I am trying to query an order table and get a count per hour....but I just get an error stating my code is wrong....but I cant see why...

```
SELECT 
,count(distinct "order_no") as requisition_cnt
,hour("z_time")-2 as date_hr
,day("z_date") as date_day
,month("z_date") as date_month
,year("z_date") as date_year
,"z_date" AS date_full
FROM "P__Lähete"
where
year("z_date") = 2021
group by
hour("z_time")-2
,day("z_date")
,month("z_date")
,year("z_date")
,"z_date"
order by
"z_date",hour("z_time")-2
```

Comment: The more I look at thew code and play with the FileMaker database, it would seem that functions cant be used in the group by statement...I mean....really??

Comment: Your observation that GROUP BY can only use actual columns, not calculated values
or (aliases or column numbers) is correct. Filemaker supports a very limited subset of SQL. Filemaker is not an SQL database and does not run SQL natively. For this reason, SQL should be your last choice, not first. Filemaker provides native methods to group and summarize data.